# Firefox extension pre-installation check

Tags: firefox-addon, dependency-management

Is there a way to do a pre-installation check before installing an extension through XPInstall? This extension contains an NPAPI plugin. That NPAPI plugin requires certain version of libraries installed beforehand otherwise installation should fail.

Answer (score 0):

No. There are some requirements that you can define in `install.rdf` - like host application (e.g. Firefox), application version and operating system. You cannot ask XPInstall to look for particular libraries before installing your extension. And your extension won't become active until it is installed.

So you should let the user install your extension and do the checks then - warn if there are issues. You would need to do this anyway, what if the user installed your extension and uninstalled a required library after that?

Comment: npapi plugin is a  .so which browser fails to load  because of a missing dependent library. Cant check if npapi plugin is not  loaded.
install.rdf, can  you please be  more specific about this?

Comment: [targetPlatform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Install_Manifests#targetPlatform) for example. You have an extension - you can write JavaScript code that will do the necessary checks (it's easiest to put it into `bootstrap.js`, see [Bootstrapped extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Bootstrapped_extensions)).

Comment: targetPlatform doesnt  seem to help. I need to figure out if certain .so version is  present  on the  machine. If i understand  correctly, targetPlatform XPCOM ABI seems to be suggesting only about Firefox, not  whats  on the machine itself. Ill take a deeper look at bootstrap.js though. Thanks  for the pointer ( thats not null :) )

Comment: I already said in my answer that `install.rdf` options aren't going to solve your problem...